# Develop a Mobile App using Icenium Graphite

Tags: c#, jquery, icenium

I want to develop an App using Icenium Graphite for cross platform(Android, ios).

This particular App will also access Database through WebApi.

I am new to Icenium Graphite so please let me know the resources which i can use for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write and app with Icenium, it's almost exactly like writing a standard HTML5 web application. Therefore, if you are accessing a service layer like Web API, you can make a standard ajax call with jQuery's $.ajax like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "http://somewhere.com/service",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (x) {
        console.log(x);
    }
});
```

Comment: can i get any sample which access the webapi in Icenium Graphite?

Comment: There are all kinds of Icenium sample apps here: http://docs.icenium.com/sample-apps/sample-apps - one that may help you especially is the Music Store app: http://docs.icenium.com/sample-apps/sample-kendo-mobile-music-store